# 'While Loop' and multiples of a variable

Tags: vb.net, loops, while-loop

This is another school project, and I'm stumped, so PLEASE help.

I'm supposed to write a program that outputs the numbers 1 to 100, however there are 4 variables. When you enter a value for Variable 1 it takes the numbers that multiples of that number and changes it to the Variable Word that you type in.

The specific question I have is how do I get my variables to be multiples of that value?

This is all I have...thank you for your help.

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub lblDiscription_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lblDiscription.Click

End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub bntCounter_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles bntCounter.Click
    Dim intCounter As Integer = 0
    Dim intLeftMultiple As Integer = 1
    Dim intRightMultiple As Integer = 1
    Dim strLeftWord As String
    Dim strRightWord As String



    While intCounter < 101
        lstDisplay.Items.Add(CStr(intCounter))
        intCounter += 1



        End If

    End While


End Sub

Private Sub lblMiddle_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lblMiddle.Click

End Sub
```

End Class

This is what my GUI Looks like.

[image]

Comment: please clarify `changes it to the Variable Word`.  you could start by getting the inputs from the form into the variables you have defined.

Comment: Do you mean you want something like `lstDisplay.Items.Add(CStr(intCounter * intLeftMultiple))`?

Comment: I think so. I'm very confused myself. So, when I type a number into txtLeftMultiple and a word into txtLeftWord all the multiples of that number are replaced by that word. And same for the ones on the right.

Comment: Read the assignment because you have to be clear what you are doing in order to get there (let alone ask for help). So, for `3` and `cat` you want to replace multiples of `3` with `cat`?  thats a lot of cats!  Still - start by getting the inputs into the variables.  Should the listbox already have the 1-100 numbers in it to start?

Comment: Yeah, I want to replace all multiples of 3 with cat. and I want to swap all multiples of ____ to _____. And I want to change all multiples of both to CAT_____.

Comment: So you need to convert the number entered in the TextBox to a numeric type variable.  Then in the While loop you need to see if `intCounter` is a multiple of that number.  This can be done using an `If` statement and the `Mod` function...look it up.

Comment: for 3/cat and 4/dog what happens at 12 which is a multiple of both? does the assignment say "fill" a listbox... or "replace" in a listbox? (you do realize we dont have the text book, right?)

Comment: Ok, thank you this gives me a great start. This is exactly what we're talking about in class.

Comment: Ok letme get this straight,u list numbers 1 -100,then perhaps u enter the number 10 so for 10,20,30 etc it replaces that with maybe horse?? whatelse?

Comment: for both numbers n words isnt it? where are u stuck this sounds fair to me especially if we use a for loop.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I need is to use a loop. I'm stuck at how I get the multiples to change to the correct word. But yes you guys got the right idea. It was hard for me to explain.